# Error al intentar importar datos en el format JSON

Tags: python-3.7

El siguiente script está pensado para importar datos desde una Web externa, en formato JSON.

```
# getting data in JSON format 

import requests, json
import pandas as pd

BASE_URL = "https://production.dataviz.cnn.io/index/fearandgreed/graphdata"
START_DATE = '2021-01-01'

r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE))
data = r.json()

fear_greed_index = pd.DataFrame(data['fear_and_greed_historical']['data'])
fear_greed_index['x'] = pd.to_datetime(fear_greed_index['x']//1000, unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
fear_greed_index = fear_greed_index.rename(columns={'x':'date','y':'fear_metric'})

fear_greed_index.drop_duplicates()
```

Me devuelve el error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6721/1538259400.py in <module>
      9 
     10 r = requests.get("{}/{}".format(BASE_URL, START_DATE))
---> 11 data = r.json()
     12 
     13 fear_greed_index = pd.DataFrame(data['fear_and_greed_historical']['data'])

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    899             if encoding is not None:
    900                 try:
--> 901                     return complexjson.loads(
    902                         self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs
    903                     )

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    344             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347     if cls is None:
    348         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

¿Cuál es la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que lo que estás recibiendo NO es un json valido.

Si imprimes el texto del request (usando `[el objeto request].text`), te muestra en pantalla el siguiente texto:

```
I'm a teapot. You're a bot.
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se imprime ese texto?, Haiendo print(r) me devuelve <Response [418]>

Comment: Usando r.text, que obtiene el texto (no el contenido) del request. Perdón, ahora lo agrego a la respuesta.